# Invalid input syntax for type numeric

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

This is the query I am working with -

```
select
    cast(date_time as date) dt,
    visit,
    visitor,
    regexp_replace(item_id ,'[^0-9]','','g') as item_id,
    sum(qty) as qty,
    sum(sales) as sales
from
( 
    select
        date_time,
        (string_to_array(x,';'))[2] as item_id,     
        cast((string_to_array(x,';'))[3] as decimal(18,0)) qty, 
        cast((string_to_array(x,';'))[4] as decimal(18,0)) sales,                                                
        visit,
        visitor
    from

    TABLE

) b
where item_id is not null and (item_id ~ '^[0-9]+$')= 't'
group by 1,2,3,4 ;
```

It was running fine before.

Recently I started receiving an error message, which says the following -

> invalid input syntax for type numeric

Comment: Check for contents of `x` field. You are relying on it holding only `;`-delimited decimal values, and guess what? - someone inserted some junk in it.

Comment: UNNEST(string_to_array(product_list,',')) as x

Comment: So what? I said "content".